# How to insert distinct elements into an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to insert distinct elements into a matrix. To do so I create an array of [rows x columns] dimension and place there each element I insert into the matrix and right after that read the array and if an element of the matrix is the same as one in the array make the user reintroduce the `[m][n]` element into the array. But doing so this doesn't work the way I expected and also looks a bit messy; how can it be more "simple"?

```
void rellenarMatriz(int **a, int f, int c) {

    int i, j, aux, k, l;

    for(i = 0; i < f; i++) {

        for(j = 0; j < c; j++) {

            //Introducir numero
            printf("    [%d][%d]> ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);

            //Comprobar que ese elemento no está en la matriz  
            contieneElemento(a, i, j);   
        }

        printf("\n");
    }    
}
```

**NOTE**: This is not homework, I am trying to learn on my own.

Solution?

```
void contieneElemento(int ** a, int ff, int cf) {

    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i <= ff; i++) {

        for(j = 0; j <= cf; j++) {

            printf("[%d][%d]>\n", i + 1, j + 1);

            do {

                printf("> Elemento repetido.\n");
                printf("   *[%d][%d]> ", ff + 1, cf + 1);
                scanf("%d", &a[ff][cf]);
            } while(a[i][j] == a[ff][cf]);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, corrected! It is `b[l - 1]`

Comment: I'd like to use only arrays/matrices and C, not C++.

Comment: Is there a reason you're maintaining two arrays rather than holding the scanned value as a temporary (e.g. `int input`) and comparing it to the matrix before inserting?

Comment: Time to start up the debugger and/or pen and paper.

Comment: Do you have an upper limit for the numbers that can be inputted?

Comment: No, just integer and unique numbers, @AnindyaDutta.

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* way is simply to look through your matrix/array to see whether or not the element you wish to insert is already there. I recommend you have a separate function that tells you.

```
bool ya_tiene_elemento( int **a, int f, int c, int hasta_f, int hasta_c, int elt )
{
  if (hasta_f > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < hasta_f-1; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        if (a[i][j] == elt) return true;
  for (int j = 0; j <= hasta_c; j++)
    if (a[hasta_f][j] == elt) return true;
  return false;
}
```

That will suffice for a toy.

If you wish to be significantly more efficient, consider using a [Bloom Filter](http://billmill.org/bloomfilter-tutorial/) to decide whether or not you wish to actually scan the matrix/array for a match.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just tried to use your idea. I am trying to use the function I added on the description but it doesn't scan all the elements, just some of them.

Comment: Correct. You should only scan those elements you have already added to the matrix. In your code, where you say 'test to see if that element is not in the matrix', use the function I provided: `if (!ya_tiene_elemento(a,f,c,i,j-1,new_number)) a[i][j] = new_number;`

Comment: @jdmg718: One of the reasons you may be running into problems is that your code looks through the whole of the array, not just the initialized portion of the array.  The solution from Dúthomhas avoids reading the uninitialized portion of the array.  However, any interactive prompting for amendments is tricky — and maybe contra-indicated.  Suppose the user redirects the input from a file? That won't respond to the edits. You need to validate that the `scanf()` operations succeed — and perhaps bail out if they don't. It might be the best strategy anyway; read the data as given and then check it.

Comment: Agree with @JonathanLeffler. You should read all input, then check for validity, and only proceed if valid or not. This offers you, BTW, a simpler test for duplicates: copy the matrix into a flat (1D) array, sort, and check for consecutive multiples.

Comment: @jdmg718: _[…continuing…]_  It's a tricky business.  If the input is from a file, then read-and-reject is good.  If the user's typing the data, it is cruel to make them type 50 numbers only to reject the whole matrix because the third one was mistyped.  But one of the first things I'd do were I using the program is make sure the data can be read from file — because then I can edit the data and ensure there are no mistakes.